# Next.js: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, firebase-authentication

The code below initially works but once I reload the page I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')`.

```
  const [folders, setFolders] = useState([]);

  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

  const folderColRef = collection(db, "UsersData", user?.uid, "Folders");
  useEffect(() => {
    const getFolders = async () => {
      const userData = await getDocs(folderColRef);
      setFolders(userData.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };
    getFolders();
  }, []);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This typically means that you're passing `undefined` to the `collection` functions, which is not allowed. In your code that means that `user` is `null`, which is actually the normal behavior when the page first loads (as restoring the user's authentication state requires an asynchronous call to the server).

My guess is that you'll need to have the effect depend on the user variable, and then handle the `null`/`undefined` inside of that:

```
const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!user) return; //  Add this line
  const folderColRef = collection(db, "UsersData", user!.uid, "Folders");  //  Move this line
  const getFolders = async () => {
    const userData = await getDocs(folderColRef);
    setFolders(userData.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
  };
  getFolders();
}, [user]);  //  Add a dependency here
```